# need script to add line to xml file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

for all files containing a line like:

```
 <class name="blahblahblah" foo="bar" fooz="baz">
```

I would like to add this line right afterwards.

```
 <cache usage="read-write">
```

The key text for searching is

```
  <class name=
```

I have access to a bash shell for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please get hold of proper XML tools. Sed and grep aren't fit for handling XML; it may look like plain text, but looks are deceiving.

Comment: Thanks, larsmans. But, there is nothing specific to XML in this question. I simply need to add a single line of text at a certain point in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
sed -i '/<class name=*/ a\
<cache usage="read-write">' filename.xml
```

and remember it is just one single command. The -i option (--in-place) changes the given file (in place).

Answer (score 0):

Is Awk an option?

```
awk '{ print; if ($0 ~ "<class name=") print "<cache usage=\"read-write\">"; }'
```

(Though I still strongly object to using line-oriented tools on XML files. A decent XML toolset saves you a lot of trouble in the long run.)